# Very low throughput on 10GbE network

Tags: networking, performance, ethernet, 10gbethernet

I have two Linux machines, each equipped with a [Solarflare SFN5122F](http://www.solarflare.com/Enterprise-10GbE-Adapters) 10GbE NIC. The two NICs are connected together with an SFP+ Direct Attach cable.

I am using [netperf](http://www.netperf.org/netperf/#) to measure TCP throughput between the two machines. On one box, I run:

```
netserver
```

and on the other:

```
netperf -t TCP_STREAM -H 192.168.x.x -- -m 32768
```

I get:

```
MIGRATED TCP STREAM TEST from 0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0) port 0 AF_INET to 192.168.x.x (192.168.x.x) port 0 AF_INET
Recv   Send    Send                          
Socket Socket  Message  Elapsed              
Size   Size    Size     Time     Throughput  
bytes  bytes   bytes    secs.    10^6bits/sec  

 87380  16384  32768    10.02    1321.34
```

The measured throughput is 1.3Gb/s. This is 7.5x below the theoretical maximum, and only 30% faster than 1GbE.

What steps can I take to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Did you enable jumbo frames?

Comment: Do you get low throughput on UDP tests as well?

Comment: @gekkz: Changing MTU to 9000 on both ends made no perceptible difference.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: UDP throughput is about the same.

Comment: Then is the CPU of the sending system the bottleneck?  Random data generation at that speed can be expensive.

Comment: What is the hardware of the boxes involved? You cannot achieve 10GbE line rate with anything less than modern Westmere/Nehalem/Sandy Bridge boxes.

Comment: I've had the exact same problem for over a year. I think the problem is with 10GbE. I'm thinking that even 8Gbps Fibre Channel is much better at throughput than 10GbE.

Answer (score 6):

few things:

- did you try adjusting mtu to [make use of jumbo-frames](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-debian-ubuntu-jumbo-frames-configuration/)?
- are you absolutely sure that the link between the two servers does not have any packet losses?
- does ethtool show you any errors on the interfaces on both ends?
- what does top/atop say during the prolonged test - do you see any of the cores fully occupied by iowait?

you'll [most probably] not achieve full 10gbit on a single tcp session but you can do some additional tuning to get closer to it by tweaking tcp handling and communication with the network card itself - take a look [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/ols/2009/ols2009-pages-169-184.pdf) or [here](http://docs.rodecker.nl/10-GE_Routing_on_Linux.pdf) .